# Get list in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm struggling with a nested loop..

I have a dictionary with other dictionaries nested in it, like:

```
dd = {}

dd[1] = {'layer1' : 'A', 'FieldA':[[1,2,3], [99,22,13]], 'col': '#ff310021'}
dd[2] = {'layer2' : 'B', 'FieldB':[[4,5,6], [10,33,22]], 'col': '#ff310011'}
dd[3] = {'layer3' : 'C', 'FieldC':[[11,2,33], [2,5,1]], 'col': '#ff312221'}
```

Then I have an object that has to be populated, **for each dd keys** (so 3 times in the example) with the values of the nested dictionaries.

This is an example with *single* values passed to the object:

```
Plot(
x = [1,2,3],
y = [4,5,6],
col = '#ff312221'
)
```

The object creates another class that will be used in another context.

However each call to the object has to be appended to a list.

What I'm trying to do is to loop over the dictionary keys to fill the object automatically and append the result to a list.

So, with the example data, the first object should be made like:

```
l = []

l.append(Plot(
x = [1,2,3],
y = [99,22,13],
col = '#ff310021'
))
```

Someone has some hints?

Comment: Hint: `for key in dd:` will iterate through your keys. doing something like `currentDict = dd[key]` will make `currentDict` reference the dict at that key. Since you have a constant form for each dict, you can grab values using keys again, ie. `currentDict['col']` will return the `'col'` value for whatever dict you are currently in.

Comment: I'm not sure what the part you're having trouble with is. You've said that you want to loop over the dictionary keys. Do you know how to start writing that loop? If so, can you write as much as you can and then tell us where you've gotten stuck?

Comment: Why do you have `x` in the first line but `y` in the two following lines in your example?

Comment: There is something wrong about the layers and your question. `x`  and `y` are mixed with the layer... can you be more clear on what you trying to do ?

Comment: @RNar thanks for the answer.. but I don't get it.. do you mean looping of the keys with ``for key in dd``, but then ``currentDict = dd[key]`` will be filled with just the last value of the starting dict..

Comment: `currentDict = dd[key]` would be in your for loop.

Comment: sorry guys, I had mixed the dictionaries.. I edited the question..

Comment: do you need z in your Plot ? like Plot(x,y,z,col) ?

Comment: @LAL.. no no, they are just example names.. The nested lists in each dictionary are the ``x`` and ``y`` for each layer.. Sorry for the confusing names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
dd = {}

dd[1] = {'layer1' : 'A', 'FieldA':[[1,2,3], [99,22,13]], 'col': '#ff310021'}
dd[2] = {'layer2' : 'B', 'FieldB':[[4,5,6], [10,33,22]], 'col': '#ff310011'}
dd[3] = {'layer3' : 'C', 'FieldC':[[11,2,33], [2,5,1]], 'col': '#ff312221'}

l = []

for key in dd:
    x, y = dd[key].get('FieldA', None) or dd[key].get('FieldB', None) or dd[key].get('FieldC', None)
    col = dd[key]['col']

    l.append(Plot(x=x, y=y, col=col))
```

Comment: I like the way you use the logic or.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in dd:
    if 'FieldA' in dd[i]:
        x = dd[i]['x'][0]
        y = dd[i]['x'][1]
    if 'FieldB' in dd[i]:
        x = dd[i]['y'][0]
        y = dd[i]['y'][1]
    if 'FieldC' in dd[i]:
        x = dd[i]['z'][0]
        y = dd[i]['z'][1]
    col = dd[i]['col']
    print x, y, col
    l.append(Plot(x,y,col))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to iter on the `dd.items()` dict you'll get it's keys and values:

```
>>> for key, value in dd.items():
...     print(key, value)
1 {'col': '#ff310021', 'layer1': 'A', 'x': [[1, 2, 3], [99, 22, 13]]}
2 {'layer2': 'B', 'col': '#ff310011', 'y': [[4, 5, 6], [10, 33, 22]]}
3 {'col': '#ff312221', 'y': [[11, 2, 33], [2, 5, 1]], 'layer3': 'B'}
```

So for each item you may get the `'x'` or the `'y'` key:

```
l = []
for key, value in dd.items():
    try:
        cords = value['x']
    except KeyError:
        cords = value['y']
    l.append(
       Plot(x=cords[0], y=cords[1], col=value['col'])
    )
```

You may also create a generator instead of appending to `l`:

```
def build_plots(plot_dict):
    for key, value in plot_dict.items():
        try:
            cords = value['x']
        except KeyError:
            cords = value['y']
        yield Plot(x=cords[0], y=cords[1], col=value['col'])
```

And consume it by doing this:

```
for plot in build_plots(dd):
    print(plot)
```

I hope it helps!